# How to pass close a stage and return to PREVIOUS stage with a value WITHOUT opening a new stage?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I want that when I click insert Button(on first stage), it opens a new stage and there I want to enter a number and click insert and it closes the second and goes back to first window and prints the Inserted number in the link list.
Everything is working fine except that when I click the insert button at second stage, it doesn't go back to first, rather it opens new stage and shows me the inserted number, in this way if I add multiple numbers, it only outputs the latest number I added. So I want to know that how to go back to previous stage when I click insert(on 2nd stage) without opening a new stage.

Here is My Code of Main:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AppletProject extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("LLApplet.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Here is My Code of controller of first stage(Home):

```
public class HomeController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button insertbutton;
    @FXML
    private TextArea outputTextArea;

    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    } 

    @FXML
    private void insertButton(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Insert Screen.fxml"));

        Stage stage = new Stage();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public void insert(int d) {
        Node newNode = new Node(d);
        newNode.setNext(head);
        if (head != null){
            head.setPrevious(newNode);
        }
        head = newNode ;
        outputTextArea.setText(displayList().toString());
    }

    public StringBuilder displayList(){
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        Node iterator = head ;
        while (iterator != null){
            Print print = new Print(iterator.getData());
                str.append(print);
            iterator = iterator.getNext() ;
            if (iterator != null)
                str.append("->");
        }
        str.append("\n");
        return str;
    }
}
```

Here is My Code of controller of second stage(Insert Screen):

```
public class InsertScreenController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField insertTextField;
    @FXML
    private Button insertButton;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    } 
    HomeController home = new HomeController();
    Node head = home.head;
    @FXML
    private void insertButton(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Home.fxml"));

            Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
            HomeController home = loader.getController();
            home.output(Integer.parseInt(insertTextField.getText()));


            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            Stage window = (Stage)((javafx.scene.Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

            window.setScene(scene);
            window.close();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(InsertScreenController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    }
    Here is my Node Class:


    public class Node {
    private int data ;
    private Node next ;
    private Node previous ;

    public Node(){
        data = 0 ;
        next = null ;
    }

    public Node (int data){
        this.data = data ;
    }

    public Node (int data, Node next, Node previous){
        this.data = data ;
        this.next = next ;
        this.previous = previous ;
    }


    public int getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public Node getPrevious(){
        return previous ;
    }

    public void setData(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }   

    public void setPrevious(Node previous){
        this.previous = previous ; 
    } 
}
```

Here is my Print class:

```
class Print{
    int data;

    public Print(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.format("[%d]",data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're reloading the scene and creating a new window on a click of the insert button. What you need to do instead is communicating with the previously created scene. You can accomplish this by passing a suitable object (or multiple objects) to the new scene as described in the question [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml)

However you can also make use of nested event loops: `Stage.showAndWait` blocks until the `Stage` is closed, so you could use this to query the input results and just prepare the result and close the window on a click of the button. The following example doesn't use fxml, but getting your hands on the controller using `FXMLLoader.getController` after loading the fxml with an instance method of an `FXMLLoader` instance you used to load the fxml can allow you to communicate with the scene loaded. (The linked question contains some good answers basically showing you how to do this.)

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
    Button button = new Button("Add item");

    button.setOnAction(evt -> {
        // create scene for inputing string
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        Button ok = new Button("OK");

        Scene dialogScene = new Scene(new VBox(textField, ok));
        Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
        dialogStage.setScene(dialogScene);

        // make sure the user cannot interact with original stage while the new one is opened
        dialogStage.initOwner(stage);

        // very simple way of storing the return value; replace with something better
        String[] resultContainer = new String[1];

        ok.setOnAction(e -> {
            // store dialog result & info that the user closed the window using the button
            resultContainer[0] = textField.getText();

            dialogStage.close();
        });

        // show window and wait for user to finish the input
        dialogStage.showAndWait();

        String result = resultContainer[0];
        if (result != null) {
            // deal with user input
            listView.getItems().add(result);
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(listView, button));

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Note that the `Dialog` class may be worth consideration since it includes functionality to get a result directly from its `showAndWait` method, but you may not want to be restricted to using a `DialogPane`...